# JavaScript - h1 replace based on url parameters javascript, how to add more than one word in url and on the page?

Tags: javascript

with a url of http://example.com?productName=Walkman is working right

```
<body>
    <h1 id="productName"></h1>
</body>


<script type='text/javascript'>
    // start by creating a function 
    function loadUp(){
        var str = window.location.search.replace(/(?:(\D+=))/ig, "") //get the search parameters from the url and remove everything before the "=" sign
        document.getElementById('productName').innerHTML = str //assign that string to the "innerHTML" of the h1 tag that has an id of "productName"
    };

    window.onload = loadUp; // once the page has loaded, fire off that function
</script>
```

the problem is that if i add 2 or more words in the URL
http://example.com?productName=Best_Walkman
on the page i have **Best_Walkman** but i want to show  **Best Walkman**

> how can i hide this symbol on th website _ ? inide the tag

```
<h1 id="productName"></h1>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Encode URL in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/encode-url-in-javascript)

Comment: I'm not sure how to implement that maybe some code examples? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add another `replace`

```
    str = window.location.search.replace(/(?:(\D+=))/ig, "").replace("_"," ")
```

edit

for all `_` to be replaced, you need to replace using regex

```
 replace(/(?:(\D+=))/ig, "").replace(/_/g," ")
```

Comment: very good the problem is that replaced just the first _  what if i have more than 2 words ?

Comment: this code right now is removing just one _  symbol, i have this 
 Best_Walkman_Best_Walkman  what is the solution for this ?

Comment: Problem resolved thank you  
str = window.location.search.replace(/(?:(\D+=))/ig, "").replace("_"," ").replace("_"," ").replace("_"," ").replace("_"," ").replace("_"," ")

Comment: @IvanDern i have edited my solution to replace all the _

Comment: i have one more question  do you know how to make it show more than one time on the page <h1 id="productName"></h1>   the title right now  is not showing in multiple places

Comment: ID is only for a single element, if you want to do it for multiple, you need to use class @IvanDern

Answer (score 0):

```
str = window.location.search.replace(/(?:(\D+=))/ig, "").replace("_"," ").replace("_"," ").replace("_"," ").replace("_"," ").replace("_"," ")
```

This is my solution so far, if you have something better, please post it.